# CSS Transform scale - image still takes up space

Tags: css, transform

When the following CSS property is added to an image, the image still occupies the same space that it did when it was sized at 100%? Is there a way to make the text fill the space around this image?

```
transform: scale(0.2);
height: auto;
float: right;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how transform works as I understand it. It only changes the appearance **visually**; the actual dimensions of the *original* object are maintained.

You would have to adjust the width/height of the image rather than use transform.

#### Demo in [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w4xa9b4o/1/) & StackSnippets:

```css
div {
  background: #bae5fc;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
  padding: 4px;
}

img {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.trans:hover img {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.dimen:hover img {
  max-width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="trans">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="" />
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas sequi fugit quis ipsam veniam dicta sint aliquid magnam deleniti doloribus rerum laudantium eveniet expedita ipsa ducimus vero fuga optio dolor hic adipisci minima dolorem nemo mollitia?
    Autem repellat minus aliquam odit magni deserunt quibusdam voluptas repellendus ipsum recusandae rem nisi dolor sunt veritatis quas sapiente maiores consectetur sequi laudantium saepe. Recusandae deserunt quidem rerum quia enim possimus sed iure aliquid
    a consectetur magnam molestias voluptas vero nisi adipisci sequi libero natus illum facere praesentium deleniti tempora nam quas ducimus corporis maiores placeat expedita est cupiditate ipsam modi cumque quos eveniet totam illo nemo harum commodi
    odio aliquam quo eaque pariatur. Minima eum deleniti impedit!
  </p>
</div>

<div class="dimen">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="" />
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas sequi fugit quis ipsam veniam dicta sint aliquid magnam deleniti doloribus rerum laudantium eveniet expedita ipsa ducimus vero fuga optio dolor hic adipisci minima dolorem nemo mollitia?
    Autem repellat minus aliquam odit magni deserunt quibusdam voluptas repellendus ipsum recusandae rem nisi dolor sunt veritatis quas sapiente maiores consectetur sequi laudantium saepe. Recusandae deserunt quidem rerum quia enim possimus sed iure aliquid
    a consectetur magnam molestias voluptas vero nisi adipisci sequi libero natus illum facere praesentium deleniti tempora nam quas ducimus corporis maiores placeat expedita est cupiditate ipsam modi cumque quos eveniet totam illo nemo harum commodi
    odio aliquam quo eaque pariatur. Minima eum deleniti impedit!
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Edit: it just takes ages to load

Comment: Swapped for placebacon...Mmmmm bacon!