# Shrink an outer div to the size of a scaled (transformed) inner div

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have an inner div that has been scaled by an arbitrary amount. I would like the size of the container div to be that of the inner div, but instead it is sized as if the inner contents were not scaled. How can I get it to shrinkwrap correctly?

```css
#content {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#scaler {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

#outer {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="scaler">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not just apply the transform to outer if you want it to be the same size as scaler? But that's how transforms work - the element will still take the full space of the original, therefore the parent can't shrink: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802677/css-transform-scale-image-still-takes-up-space and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141902/transform-scale-keeps-the-original-space-around-the-scaled-element

Comment: transform is merely a visual effect, it doesn't affect elements around it.

Comment: Not possible using CSS. The whole purpose of `transform` is to detach the rendered layer from the actual document flow and modify the first while not touching the latter. But it's possible via JavaScript, using a three wrapper system.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu if you apply the transform to the parent, then you wouldn't have any red outside of the blue (which is what I think OP is wanting), but as the rest of my comment explains, it still takes up the space of the original without the transform

Comment: @Pete, but then the parent would have **all** its content shrinked, and that's not what's desired here. Only that particular child should shrink, while everything else remains at the same scale.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu depends if there's anything else in it though, with the current structure it wouldn't make any difference applying it to the outer (apart from getting the desired "shrink" effect) - which is why I asked the question why not apply it to the outer.  As OP has not responded, then we cannot give an answer for certain, anyway you deleted your original comment so I've left this and moved on

Comment: @Pete, so you moved the problem from `.scaler` to `.outer`, which now still occupies a different space in document flow than what it appears to. How does that solve the problem?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Because now you don't have any red overflowing from the blue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184276/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-pete).

Comment: How's the scaling is applied ? and is the `#content` dimensions always hard coded ?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu and Pete sorry for not getting back right away. The component that I am scaling is a widget in my application that I would like to control the size of, and have the application around it act *as if* it were that smaller size. I do have control of the outer application, so could use JS on it if necessary. A pure CSS solution, or at least one that minimizes the JS (the outer UI is complex) would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too nice a challenge to pass.
Pretty sure **not** achievable via CSS alone, I expected it to be easier with JS.

Ended up as a bit of both:

```js
class zoomFactor {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = this.query(el, document);
    this.update();
    this.query('input').addEventListener('input', () => this.update());
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => this.update())
  }

  query(s, el = this.el) {
    return el.querySelector(s);
  }

  value() {
    return this.query('input') ? 
      this.query('input').value :
      parseFloat(this.el.dataset('scale')) || 1;
  }

  update() {
    let val = this.value(),
      z1 = this.query('z-1'),
      z2 = this.query('z-2'),
      z3 = this.query('z-3');
    z1.style = z2.style = z3.style = '';
    z2.style.width = z1.clientWidth * val + 'px';
    z1.style.width = z2.style.width;
    z3.style.transform = 'scale(' + val + ')';
    z3.style.width = z2.clientWidth / val + 'px';
    z1.style.height = z3.clientHeight * val + 'px';
  }
}

new zoomFactor('zoom-factor');
```

```css
.range {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.range input {
  width: 70%;
}

zoom-factor {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

z-1,
z-2,
z-3 {
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

z-1 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em 1em .35em;
}

z-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

z-3 {
  transform-origin: left top;
  background-color: blue;
}
z-3 p {
  text-align: justify;
}
p,
h3 {
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

z-3>*:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<zoom-factor>
  <div class="range">
    <input type="range" value=".8" min="0.05" max="1.95" step="0.01">
  </div>
  <z-1>
    <z-2>
      <z-3>
        <h3>Transformed content</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet. Non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Sed euismod nisi porta
          lorem mollis aliquam ut. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Nibh situs amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Dolor morbi non arcu
          risus. Venenatis urna cursus eget nunc.</p>

        <p>In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio. Arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim
          diam quis. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis. Consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna. Faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum. Nam libero
          justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum. Imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem. Varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius. Aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id
          cursus metus. Non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor.</p>
      </z-3>
    </z-2>
  </z-1>
  <h3>Normal content</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet. Non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Sed euismod nisi porta lorem
    mollis aliquam ut. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Dolor morbi non arcu risus. Venenatis
    urna cursus eget nunc.</p>

  <p>In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio. Arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam
    quis. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis. Consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna. Faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum. Nam libero justo laoreet
    sit amet cursus sit amet dictum. Imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem. Varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius. Aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus. Non curabitur
    gravida arcu ac tortor.</p>

  <p>In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. Porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat. Mattis rhoncus urna neque
    viverra. Euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet. Adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec. Risus sed vulputate odio ut. Augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque.
    Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet. At quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.</p>

  <p>In arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh. Adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin. Dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in. Felis eget nunc lobortis mattis. Pellentesque dignissim enim sit
    amet. Senectus et netus et malesuada. A lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio. Congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue. Sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed. Ullamcorper
    a lacus vestibulum sed arcu.</p>

  <p>Varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem. Odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat. Tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Sed sed risus pretium quam. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Sit amet porttitor
    eget dolor morbi. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat. Maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus. Accumsan tortor posuere
    ac ut consequat semper viverra. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Sed velit dignissim sodales ut. Tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam.
    Aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla.</p>
</zoom-factor>
```

Most likely you won't want the `input[type="range"]` and want to control the scale from outside. You can simply pass `<zoom-factor>` a `data-scale` attribute and init it:

```
const zFactor = new zoomFactor('zoom-factor');
```

You don't really need to store it in a `const`, but it's useful for changing the scale:

```
zFactor.el.dataset('scale') = 0.5;
zFactor.update();
```

I'll probably wrap it up as a plugin, but I want to test it cross-browser and provide a few more options (i.e. allow changing the transform origin to center or right, create an auto-init method, etc...), to make it more flexible.

Comment: Thank you! This is a more full-featured solution that what I ended up doing, but is essentially the same. After realizing there was no pure-css way to do it, I simply grabbed the `getBoundingClientRect()` from the scaled component, and set the width and height of the container: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vQaLVG