# Why do I continue to get a scroll bar when scaling down a large box?

Tags: html, css

In simple terms I am trying to scale a large box (used when the browser is in full screen) down to a smaller box using the CSS transform property. The box is scaling properly but the browser is still showing the scroll bars as if it is not scaled. I do not want to turn off overflow, I am hoping I am missing something.

A fiddle of my issue. Notice the vertical scroll bar:
http://jsfiddle.net/adamlj/uvfhr8nw/4/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .scaleme {
                background: red;
                height: 2000px;
                width: 4000px;
            }

            .scaler {
                transform-origin: top left;
                transform: scale(0.16666667);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="scaler">
            <div class="scaleme"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transform` leaves the original element untouched. It only affects how the element is rendered.

But the original element remains the same, hence occupying the same space in document flow. So the scrollbars will not go away unless you resize the element.

If you're looking for a solution to resize both the element and the space it occupies in document flow, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53490953/1891677).

```js
"use strict";var _createClass=function(){function e(e,t){for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){var i=t[n];i.enumerable=i.enumerable||!1,i.configurable=!0,"value"in i&&(i.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(e,i.key,i)}}return function(t,n,i){return n&&e(t.prototype,n),i&&e(t,i),t}}();function _classCallCheck(e,t){if(!(e instanceof t))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}var zoomFactor=function(){function e(t){_classCallCheck(this,e),this.el=this.q(t,document),this.b(),this.u()}return _createClass(e,[{key:"q",value:function(e){return(arguments.length>1&&void 0!==arguments[1]?arguments[1]:this.el).querySelector(e)}},{key:"b",value:function(){var e=this.el.innerHTML,t=document.createElement("z-1"),n=document.createElement("z-2"),i=document.createElement("z-3"),l=document.createElement("style");this.el.innerHTML="",this.el.appendChild(t),t.appendChild(n),n.appendChild(i),i.innerHTML=e,l.appendChild(document.createTextNode("z-1,z-2,z-3,zoom-factor{display:block}z-1,zoom-factor{position:relative;overflow:hidden}z-1,z-2{width:100%}z-1,z-2,z-3{color:#fff}z-1{float:left;overflow:hidden}z-2{position:absolute}z-3{transform-origin:left top;width:0}")),document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(l)}},{key:"v",value:function(){return this.q("input")?this.q("input").value:parseFloat(this.el.dataset.scale)||1}},{key:"u",value:function(){var e=this.v(),n=this.q("z-1"),i=this.q("z-2"),l=this.q("z-3");n.style=i.style=l.style="",i.style.width=n.clientWidth*e+"px",l.style.transform="scale("+e+")",n.style.height=l.clientHeight*e+"px"}}]),e}();new zoomFactor("zoom-factor");
```

```css
.scaleme {
  background: red;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<zoom-factor data-scale="0.16666667">
  <div class="scaleme"></div>
</zoom-factor>
```

Placed the CSS inside the JS, ran it through babel to make it es2015 compatible and minified it. Once you place that js in your page, it will automatically parse the `<zoom-factor>` element according to its `data-scale`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! That was the answer that I needed. In the end I ended up reversing my scaling from large -> small... to small -> large. So the dom elements I was dealing with were small and rendered large.

Your answer totally helped me get on the right track. Cheers!